# Get textarea value from google document ui into gs code

Tags: html, user-interface, google-apps-script, google-docs

I want to set the values of 2 variables in a gs code to be the text value in 2 text areas on the HTML file.

sidebar.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="go go go!" onclick="google.script.run.mainFunction();"/> 
    <strong>Text Area 1</strong>
    <textarea id="textarea1" rows="2" cols="35">Text1</textarea>
    <strong>Text Area 2</strong>
    <textarea id="textarea2" rows="3" cols="35">Text2</textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

code.gs:

```
mainFunction() {
  var textArea1Value = ???; // should be "Text1"/user's input
  var textArea2Value = ???; // should be "Text2"/user's input
  // some code
}
```

How do I achieve this? (what should I write instead of the "???" in the gs code?)

I've tried searching for a solution, but wasn't sure how to implement what I've found as the answers were too specific

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You need to pass the values as paramaters from the clientside to serverside

For this, obtain the textareas by `id` within a Javascript code part and pass their values to `google.script.run`

Sample modification o your code:

sidebar.html:

```js
    <input type="button" value="go go go!" onclick="myJSFunction()"/> 
    <strong>Text Area 1</strong>
    <textarea id="textarea1" rows="2" cols="35">Text1</textarea>
    <strong>Text Area 2</strong>
    <textarea id="textarea2" rows="3" cols="35">Text2</textarea>
    <script>
    function myJSFunction(){
      var text1 = document.getElementById("textarea1").value;
      var text2 = document.getElementById("textarea2").value;
      google.script.run.mainFunction(text1, text2);
    }
    </script>
```

code.gs:

```js
function mainFunction(text1, text2) {
  var textArea1Value = text1; 
  var textArea2Value = text2;
  // some code
}
```

Comment: Great! that middle step is exactly what I was lacking. Thank you!